# 'NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!' when opening a URL through a function

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

Running Ubuntu via an Oracle VM.

I have a simple function that opens a URL, for example

```
import webbrowser

def browser():

    webbrowser.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com/")

browser()
```

The tab opens in Chrome and works fine, however I keep getting the following error in the terminal after execution

```
$ ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

I've tried running the most common solution, command line "--disable-setuid-sandbox" but keep getting met with "command not found". Is there any other potential fixes?

Comment: Have you tried `--no-sandbox`

Comment: I have, "command not found"

Comment: ummm so are you by any chance literally entering `--no-sandbox` into the command line? like without anything infront of it

Comment: Adding ```google-chrome``` in front of the command spits out the same error in the post.